# WinKey+Tab bringing up search popup rather than Virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I am running Windows 10 21H1 and when I use the keyboard  shortcut <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>, instead of getting the virtual desktops overlay I get a popup window looking for a search input:
[image]

What is this? How can I get rid of it and have standard Virtual desktops behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you have installed PowerToys from Microsoft. This search bar is activated by default.

You can open the *PowerToys Settings* > *PowerToys Run* and either disable it or change the *Activation shortcut*.

Comment: Super, thank you!!! I use PowerToys but was not aware of that option.
I raised a [bug on them](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/13850)